# Triggering timer as movie clips enter the stage and stopping them when movie clips leave the stage [as3]

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone please tell me how to write the code for making a timer to start when a movie clip enters the stage and the timer to stop when the movie clip moves out of the stage.

I have placed certain movie clips outside the stage and have made them move from right to left across the stage (of course, on an x axis, 3 pixels at a time). As each movie clip enters the stage, a related timer should be triggered. When the timer is triggered, it will start playing a specific audio clip on every two second interval. And when the movie clip moves out of the stage, the timer should stop, so that the mp3 audio will also be stopped. KINDLY SUGGEST SOME **NON-OOP** WAYS OF DOING IT. Its just the "triggering" and "stopping" part that i need.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)
function loop(e:Event){
if(e1.x <= -250){e1.x = 1250;}
if(e2.x <= -350){e2.x = 1325;}
if(e3.x <= -450){e3.x = 1400;}
if(e4.x <= -550){e4.x = 1475;}
if(e5.x <= -650){e5.x = 1550;}
if(e6.x <= -750){e6.x = 1625;}

e1.x -= 3;  
e2.x -= 3;
e3.x -= 3;  
e4.x -= 3;
e5.x -= 3;  
e6.x -= 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost doing it already:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)
function loop(e:Event){

if(e1.x <= -250)
{
    e1.x = 1250;
    timerE1.stop()
    timerE1.reset()
}
else if(e1.x >= 1250)
{
     timerE1.start()
}

if(e2.x <= -350)
{
    e2.x = 1325;
    timerE2.stop()
    timerE2.reset()
}
else if(e2.x >= 1325)
{
     timerE2.start()
}


if(e3.x <= -450)
{
    e3.x = 1400;
    timerE3.stop()
    timerE3.reset()
}
else if(e3.x >= 1400)
{
     timerE3.start()
}


if(e4.x <= -550)
{
    e4.x = 1475;
    timerE4.stop()
    timerE4.reset()
}
else if(e4.x >= 1475)
{
     timerE4.start()
}


if(e5.x <= -650)
{
    e5.x = 1550;
    timerE5.stop()
    timerE5.reset()
}
else if(e5.x >= 1550)
{
     timerE5.start()
}


if(e6.x <= -750)
{
    e6.x = 1625;
    timerE6.stop()
    timerE6.reset()
}
else if(e6.x >= 1625)
{
     timerE6.start()
}

e1.x -= 3;  
e2.x -= 3;
e3.x -= 3;  
e4.x -= 3;
e5.x -= 3;  
e6.x -= 3;
}
```

Comment: Glitcher thanks a lot for your help. Can u pls help me with another problem. I wish 16 movie clips to enter the stage, horizontally, one at a time, but Randomly, and the process should continue. I have the code written but it needs editing and modification. Ur mail id pls !!

Comment: Glitcher, I wish to send you the .fla file so that you can Understand what i am struggling to convey.

Comment: paste your code into pastebin.com and comment me the link on here. I'll take a look

Comment: It's private :S please make it public :)